# Pandas: Deleting corresponding rows in 2+ DataFrames

Tags: pandas

I have 2 DataFrames:

```
dfA:      dfB:
    n1         n2
a - AA    01 - 0
b - BB    02 - 0
c - CC    03 - 0
d - DD    04 - 1
e - EE    05 - 2
f - FF    06 - 0
```

Number of rows in dfA and dfB is always equal.

Now, I'm deleting all rows with 0 values from dfB by:

```
dfB = dfB[dfB['n2']!=0]
```

(Most likely 0 rows appear only on top or (top and bottom) of DataFrames.)

How to go about deleting corresponding rows from dfA?

Comment: Are they identically indexed?

Comment: No, different indices, but if I have to I can temporarily change them.

Comment: I can concatenate them by axis=1  and then trim but is there a simpler method? DataFrames are rather big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dfB` to make a boolean array.  Then use it as a mask for both dataframes.

```
m = dfB.n2.eq(0).values

dfB = dfB[m]
dfA = dfA[m]
```

---

**Debugging**
*Copy/Paste this*

```
dfB = pd.DataFrame(dict(n2=[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0]), '01 02 03 04 05 06'.split())

m = dfB.n2.eq(0).values

dfB[m]
```

Comment: @Ranny I edited my post.  Copy and paste the section I labeled as **Debugging**  That code should work.  I suspect you are getting an error because you've run the code to subset `dfB` twice.  Once run and a subsetted version of `dfB` has been assigned to overwrite `dfB`, it won't work again unless you reset the entire dataframe.

Comment: strange.  My org dfA is recalculated, I create m out of it - ok, apply dfA[m] and get unchanged dfA.

Comment: What do you mean you calculate `m` out of it?  It's supposed to be calculated from `dfB.n2.eq(0).values`.  Also, look at values of `m`.  Are they all `True`?  If so when you slice, you get back same array.

Comment: Got it. Silly mistake! (as usual :)

How to express

 'dfB.n2.eq(0).values' to ger not equat 0 ?

Comment: `%timeit dfB.n2.eq(not 0).values`

1000 loops, best of 3: 299 µs per loop ...........................................

`%timeit (x.l0pl!=0).values` 

1000 loops, best of 3: 222 µs per loop

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the value of the index using get_indexer_for, which returns a list of index locations (as opposed to index values)

```
dfB.index.get_indexer_for(dfB[dfB['n2'] != 0].index)
```

Then you can use those to drop the corresponding values in dfA as follows

```
dfA.drop(dfa.index[dfB.index.get_indexer_for(dfB[dfB['n2'] != 0].index)])
```

Make sure to reassign the df as this operation does not modify existing dataframe. It just makes a copy of it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with get_indexer_for. for some reason it doesn't work, as result I get unchanged dfA.

 Did: dfA = dfA.drop(dfB.index.get_indexer_for(dfB[dfB['n2'] != 0].index))

Comment: Hmm.. that's strange; it worked for me.  You could alternatively use get_loc (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) but this takes a single value, so you will have to iterate through the list of indices, which is not the worst idea but certainly not optimal.

Comment: Try this: dfA.drop(dfA.index[dfB.index.get_indexer_for(dfB[dfB['n2'] != 0].index)])

Comment: I tried this. get no change in dfA. Instead I did this :   -dfA.iloc[dfB.index.get_indexer_for(dfB[dfB['l0pl'] != 0].index)]- and it works. I need to know more about get_indexer_for command.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think. I need the same index for this to work. Thx again for help.

Comment: Well, you should print out what each of the parts of the function do, and you'll see how it works step by step :)